# Replace some words in string, but keep another

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, iteration

I'm trying to replace some words in string, so we have an encoded string:

`%3Cscript%20async%20src%3D%22%2F%2Fpagead2.googlesyndication.com%2F%25dontreplace%25%2Fjs%2Fadsbygoogle.js%22%3E%3C%2Fscript%3E%0A%3Cins%20class%3D%E2%80%9C%25dontreplace%25%22%0Astyle%3D%22display%3Ainline-block%3Bwidth%3A300px%3Bheight%3A250px%22%0Adata-ad-client%3D%22ca-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx%22%0Adata-ad-slot%3D%22yyyyyyyyyyyy%E2%80%9D%3E%0Aparams%20%3D%20%7B%0Apuid1%3A%E2%80%99%25replace1%25%E2%80%99%2C%0Apuid2%3A%E2%80%99%25replace2%25%27%2C%0Apuid3%3A%27%25replace3%25%27%0A%0A%7D`

And there are a few words in it:

- `%25dontreplace%25`
- `%25dontreplace%25`
- `%25replace1%25`
- `%25replace2%25`
- `%25replace3%25`

I need to replace all `%25replaceX%25` with `%replaceX%`, but do not touch all `%25dontreplace%25` (there can be different quantity of each)

I'm trying to split it into array and do some ifelse statements, but it doesn't seem to work and I don't think it's the most elegant:

```js
var x = "%3Cscript%20async%20src%3D%22%2F%2Fpagead2.googlesyndication.com%2F%25dontreplace%25%2Fjs%2Fadsbygoogle.js%22%3E%3C%2Fscript%3E%0A%3Cins%20class%3D%E2%80%9C%25dontreplace%25%22%0Astyle%3D%22display%3Ainline-block%3Bwidth%3A300px%3Bheight%3A250px%22%0Adata-ad-client%3D%22ca-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx%22%0Adata-ad-slot%3D%22yyyyyyyyyyyy%E2%80%9D%3E%0Aparams%20%3D%20%7B%0Apuid1%3A%E2%80%99%25replace1%25%E2%80%99%2C%0Apuid2%3A%E2%80%99%25replace2%25%27%2C%0Apuid3%3A%27%25replace3%25%27%0A%0A%7D";
    console.log(x);
    var y = x.split(/(%25)/);
    console.log(y);
    var n = [];
    for (var i = 0; i <= y.length; i++) {
    if (y[i].indexOf('%25') >= 0) {
            if (y[i + 1].indexOf('request.puid') >= 0) {
            n.push('%'+y[i]+'%');
            console.log(n);
        }
    } else {
          if (y[i - 1] === undefined && y[i + 1] === '%25') {
             n.push(y[i]);
             console.log(n);
          } else if (y[i - 1] === '%25' && y[i + 1] === undefined) {
             n.push(y[i]);
             console.log(n);
          } else if (y[i - 1] === '%25' && y[i + 1] === '%25') {
             n.push('%25'+y[i]+'%25');
             console.log(n);
          }
        }   
    }
```

Is there an elegant way to solve this problem?

Comment: Have you tried looking into regular expressions?

Comment: `.replace(/%25/,"%")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.replace` with a `RegExp` using capture groups.

The `RegExp` we'll use is `RegExp(/%25replace([0-9]*)%25/, 'g')` which finds strings matching `%25replaceX%25` and the `g` finds all matches. The `()` captures the number so we can use it in the replacement text.

Something like this:

```js
var str = "%3Cscript%20async%20src%3D%22%2F%2Fpagead2.googlesyndication.com%2F%25dontreplace%25%2Fjs%2Fadsbygoogle.js%22%3E%3C%2Fscript%3E%0A%3Cins%20class%3D%E2%80%9C%25dontreplace%25%22%0Astyle%3D%22display%3Ainline-block%3Bwidth%3A300px%3Bheight%3A250px%22%0Adata-ad-client%3D%22ca-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx%22%0Adata-ad-slot%3D%22yyyyyyyyyyyy%E2%80%9D%3E%0Aparams%20%3D%20%7B%0Apuid1%3A%E2%80%99%25replace1%25%E2%80%99%2C%0Apuid2%3A%E2%80%99%25replace2%25%27%2C%0Apuid3%3A%27%25replace3%25%27%0A%0A%7D";

var newStr = str.replace(new RegExp(/%25replace([0-9]*)%25/, 'g'), "%replace$1%");

document.write(newStr)
```

Comment: Brett, thank you so much!
It works.
What is the best practices to learn RegExp?